# How do I split a table cell within a cell?

Tags: html, css

I have this table that I'm creating online for an rp.  And several of the cells call for multiple colors.  I'd figured I'd use a gradient, but black turns out to be far too over powering.

How would I split these cells?  They're not near the header, and need to be half the size of the cells themselves.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're just splitting it in 2 you can use 2 `<div>`'s with `float:left;` and `float:right;`

```
<td>
    <div style="background-color:red; float:left; height:50px; width:50px;"></div><div style="background-color:blue; float:right; height:50px; width:50px;"></div>
</td>
```

If you have to add more color variation, just add more `<div>`'s with the appropriate float designation based on which side you're adding it too.  I think that will work in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "black turns out to be far too over powering" ?

You can use linear gradients and create exact borders like in the following two classes `.x` and `.y`, notating each color twice and making a "border" between them at 50% / 51% of the gradient:

```css
table {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.x {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #fa0, #fa0 50%, #0fa 51%, #0fa 100%);
}
.y {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #dc3, #dc3 50%, #c3f 51%, #c3f 100%);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="x"></td>
    <td class="y"></td>
    <td class="x"></td>
    <td class="y"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="y"></td>
    <td class="x"></td>
    <td class="y"></td>
    <td class="x"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```